# In cucumber, is it possible to have a single stepdefinition method for int and double datatypes, if no then how to handle these different datatypes?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, ambiguous

In cucumber, is it possible to have a single stepdefinition method for int and double datatypes, if no then how to handle these different datatypes **without changing data/parameter to a similar datatype** like string or double?

For Eg.

```
Feature: Testing

Scenario: Test1
When User enters 1 
Then Print "Hello"

Scenario: Test2
When User enters 1.0 
Then don't print anything
```

When I use the following Stepdefinition with Regular Expression, matching glue code is found missing for steps "User enters 1" and "User enters 1.0" or **steps are undefined** error comes up.

```
public class test {
 
    @Then("Print {string}")
    public void print(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    @When("^User enters (\"\\d+\\.\\d+\")$")
    public void user_enters(Double double1) {
       System.out.println(double1);
    }
    @Then("don't print anything")
    public void don_t_print_anything() {
       }
}
```

But when I add the suggested steps snippet to the stepdefinition(mentioned below) then io.cucumber.core.runner.**AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException** is thrown.

```
public class test {
@When("User enters {int}")
public void user_enters(Integer int1) {
   system.out.println(int1);
}

@Then("Print {string}")
public void print(String string) {
   system.out.println(string);
}

@When("User enters {double}")
public void user_enters(Double double1) {
    system.out.println(double1);
}
 @Then("don't print anything")
 public void don_t_print_anything() {
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original regex doesn't match the step

```
^User enters (\"\\d+\\.\\d+\")$
```

Note the `"` that doesn't exist in the step

```
When User enters 1.0
```

Though since your steps are talking about user input you may want to capture it as a string instead, e.g:

```
User enters {string}
```

And then write a step like

```
When User enters "1.0"
```

Note the added `"`s.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting it, I noticed there was another issue with my regex it should've been (\\d*\\.?\\d*)

Answer (score 0):

Issue found resolved with regex `(\\d*\\.?\\d*)`